# Better energy management

Tags: battery, cpu

I'm using elementary OS since the 0.2, on different machines, and I really enjoy see this project grow bigger and bigger every year. My current machine is a ryzen laptop, and elementary runs really great, except some little bugs when installed a year ago but seems to be gone.

What instead is **VERY ANNOYING** is a lack of ***battery management and energy in general***. I'd like to have some simple options to decide what the system should do on 20% battery left (for example), and what to do on 10% battery left (example). I'd like to easily manage the ***CPU frequencie range***, like a cpufreq GUI integrated in Settings. Right now I'm using some terminal tweaks to set the range because by default turbo boost is enabled and the CPU in idle has a 65-70C **INSANE** temperature.